# outline-minor-mode and org-mode

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode

In emacs, org-mode has been enabled and have opened some *.org files. Now in the **init.el** file i am trying to enable the **outline-minor-mode** in order to fold the lines starting with "**;**" . When i try to evaluate the `(outline-minor-mode)` command i get the message "`Symbol's function definition is void: th-outline-minor-mode-init`"

Seems like the org-mode sets up the outline-minor-mode-hook

```
outline-minor-mode-hook's value is (th-outline-minor-mode-init)

  This variable may be risky if used as a file-local variable.
```

How to setup the **outline-minor-mode** for **init.el** file so that the "**;**" is treated as heading.

**Note:-** When emacs is launched with **--no-init-file** option, **outline-minor-mode** works for init.el file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doesn't org-mode use an `org-` prefix pretty consistently?

On that assumption, `th-outline-minor-mode-init` doesn't look like an org-mode function to me, so something else is probably at fault, and you'll need to find out what.

Obviously you can't `find-function` if it's void, so I'd just `M-x rgrep` your config for `th-outline-minor-mode-init` (or most likely searching for `(add-hook 'outline-minor-mode-hook 'th-outline-minor-mode-init` will find the culprit directly).

---

That issue aside, I happen to use `outline-minor-mode` in my init file (with headers being lines beginning with `;;;;`, and auto-folding the ones beginning with `;;;; *`), using the following Local Variables block at the end of the file:

```
;;; Local Variables:
;;; outline-regexp: ";;;; "
;;; eval:(progn (outline-minor-mode 1) (while (re-search-forward "^;;;; \\* " nil t) (outline-toggle-children)))
;;; End:
```

I keep a lot of documentation in the file, and with `<backtab>` bound to `outline-toggle-children` I find this a pretty convenient way to access it.

Comment: Thanks very much. I was searching for the **th-outline-minor-mode** in google and found many **org-mode** words and thought that org-mode has caused problems.